# How to combine muli-fields values and sorted time-ranges using Redis

Tags: redis

I am trying to insert time based records with multiple fields on the values (with TTL enabled).

For the multiple fields the best way to do it via Redis is using HSET:

```
 HSET user:32 name "johns" timecreated "3333311232" address "somewhere"
```

I also try to read those values via time range:

for example return all history records (for example user 32) which was inserted in the last day:

so the best for that would be storing via ZADD using scores(this time I am losing the hash-map structure for easy retrieval):

```
ZADD user:32 3333311232 "name=johns,timecreated=3333311232,address=somewhere"
```

On the top of the things I want to add TTL for each record

Any idea how I could optimize my design?

I could split into two but that will requires two queries when reading:

```
ZADD user:32 3333311232 "user:32:3333311232"  

 HMSET user:32:3333311232 name “johns” timecreated “3333311232” address="somewhere"
```

than to retrieve ill need:

```
//some range
ZRANGEBYSCORE user:32 3333311232 333331123 

result: 1389772850
now to get all information: HGETALL user:32:1389772850
```

What do you think?

Thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two methods you describe are the two common approaches. If you store the entire object in the `ZSET`, you would typically store it as a JSON string. If you don't need "random" access to the object, that's a valid approach.

I usually go for the other approach; a `ZSET` combined with hashes. the two queries are not a big deal. You could even abstract it away with a Lua script; see [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval).

Regarding the TTL, while you cannot expire individual `ZSET` values, you could expire the hash, and use [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) to listen for the `expired` event, and remove the corresponding value from the `ZSET`.

Let me know if you need some more specifics.

Comment: my purpose was to keep history of added users while having the ability to get a user by time(my key) on demand (real-time demand) what if I tell you that I need only the last 100 records (per user) and if I add more I could move old ones to another data-source for persistence. Mybe that will help you to find me the right architecture suggestion ?

Comment: In that case, you could store them as JSON objects in the `ZSET` and every time you add one, if `ZCARD` is > 100, remove the ones with the lowest score (oldest). Should work fine.

Comment: what would you do in case a user adding two users together than I  got more than one user to insert into ZSET on the same date. Can I insert into ZSET the same scoring value?

Comment: Yes sure you can. It's a set, so you cannot have identical values. But the scores can be the same, they will just be ranked equally.

Comment: How would you limit the query to perform zadd only for keys who havnt already inserted in the last X mins. for example if I zadd on key history:2 with a value only after 10 mins ill be allowed to modify history:2 again with the same value